# Strange errors with image in texfile

Tags: graphics, overleaf, arxiv

I am working on a manuscript in overleaf and it compiles perfectly there, however when I try to submit it the onsite compiler of ArXiv does not like it at all. The main error seems to stem from line 62, which is just the /caption of my image.

```
%% An example figure call using \includegraphics
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure_1.png}
\caption{The top row shows from left to right: the chop difference frames of HR2652 taken with chop angles of 0, 180, 270 and 90 degrees and the corresponding nod frames in the middle row. Note the inverted signal on the background pattern for opposing chop angles. The panels in the bottom row compare inverse chop addition with classical chopping and nodding along two chop directions. The red rectangle represents the region used for background calibration and the black square represents the region used for obtaining source counts.} 
 \label{fig:1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Does anyone have any clue of whats going on here?

Error log: https://pastebin.com/YRHUCe02

File: https://www.overleaf.com/read/rdcwwzwvhgsy

Comment: please do not use external links, the question is archived forever and will not make sense if that pastebin goes, the error is an undefined hyperref command presumably a version difference add \listfiles and compare version numbers in the two systems.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to use the `\centering` command instead of the `center` environment as the latter introduces some vertical white space when used in combination with the `figure` environment.

Comment: Your project on Overleaf already has some LaTeX compile errors—see the red notification balloon next to the "Recompile" button, something related to `\enddata` in your tables...

Comment: What I can see is that you're using \\ before and after figure and/or tables; and \colhead doesn't like being in \multicolumn. Also don't modify aastex62.cls by commenting out the hyperref package. You might try instead including a `00README.XXX` file with `nohypertex` directive when submitting to arXiv; see https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive.